# What do you call classes without methods?

Tags: programming-languages, naming, data-structures, class

What do you call classes without methods?

For example,

```
class A
{
  public string something;
  public int a;
}
```

Above is a class without any methods. Does this type of class have a special name?

Comment: A method-less class?

Comment: The technical term is *record* or *struct*.

Comment: A "property bag"

Comment: Kilian:  I prefer "glorified struct" for the added connotation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Most of the time: An anti pattern.**

Why? Because it faciliates procedural programming with "Operator" classes and data structures. You separate data and behaviour which isn't exactly good OOP.

**Often times: A DTO (Data Transfer Object)**

Read only datastructures meant to exchange data, derived from a business/domain object.

**Sometimes: Just data structure.**

Well sometimes, you just gotta have those structures to hold data that is just plain and simple and has no operations on it. But then I wouldn't use public fields but accessors (getters and setters).

Comment: I discourage everyone to do classes with only public getters/setters in java, it's brain-dead and some containers won't even run the setter/getter code (looking at Glassfish...), so either it's the default or you have a bug. I don't believe that OOP encapsulation was right, it turns out, most of the time, in most of the applications, DTOs are not only needed, but they're the most often used classes. So they're anything but antipatterns, I'd use the word "basic building blocks" instead.

Comment: They're _maybe_ an anti-pattern if you're in a strictly OO environment. For all the rest of the programming world, having data structures that are simple heterogeneous collections of fields is a clear benefit over the alternatives, and even encouraged in [one well known OO mainstay](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882).

Comment: @Aadaam: You didn't get me right. A DTO isn't an antipattern. Sometimes those objects are perfectly fine iff they are DTOs! And when Glassfish doesn't look at getters and setters, that only means that glassfish isn't well written (although it's hard in java without builtin accessors). This code ain't braindead, it's useful boilerplate.

Comment: Quick, @Aadaam.  Someone's setting a field to an invalid value, wreaking havoc when it's read later.  Throw an exception so you can detect the culprit.  The first time you have to do something like that for a public field used in 1,000 places, you'll wish for a setter.  Public fields have their place, but the getter/setter paradigm is popular for good reason.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: in one glassfish version, I had a single exception in a setter code as a test (without conditions), which never executed. The property had a private variable and two public getters-and-setters. The container simply circumvented the setter. If something actually has an invalid value, personally I prefer type classes instead of primitive values, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Falcon: I gave up on Java and moved to different languages since then; I don't think a term like "useful boilerplate" actually exists: for me, the term 'boilerplate' is a synonym for 'language design error', and java had too much of it for my eyes. Exactly these boilerplates make java development slow and impossible without an IDE. On DTO: I strongly believe in separation of data and behaviour, and I think a mix of the two should be the special case, not the norm - it extremely depends on situation of course..

Comment: I believe the traditional term is POD - plain old data [structure]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure

Comment: It's an anti-pattern in OOP, but in FP it's advised.  Suggest learning Haskell and Erlang before stupid languages like Java and C++.

Answer (score 10):

I'd call it `struct` or `record` because it is used for data storage and this is very common to languages like `C` as you can see there: [struct (C programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29). So personally I would prefer use a `struct` instead of a class that is more suitable and readable:

```
struct A
{
  public string something;
  public int a;
}
```

Usually they are used as [DTOs (Data Transfer Object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) as said the others.

Comment: The problem with struct is, that "struct" is a keyword in many languages. C# for example treats structs as value types which have different semantics. This is also true for "record" in some languages (PL/SQL).

Answer (score 5):

These are known as [Plain Old __ Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) (PO_Os) where the blank is Java or C or CIL, or whatever language you're using.

If they're being used as simple data blocks for communication, then they can be known as [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTOs).

If they're representing some externally provided data, they can be known as [Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_class).

Comment: You're thinking of PODs - a very different idea. POJOs explicitly include "business logic", but exclude dependencies on particular frameworks.

Comment: PODs are allowed to have methods, at least in C++. They just have to have only trivial constructors, destructor, copy constructors and assignment constructors, only public data members, no base classes and no virtual functions. Basically, they just have to be compatible with C structs.

Answer (score 2):

I would call such a class a mutable data holder, and have sometimes used a generic form:

```
class DataHolder<T>
{
   public T dat;
}
```

Note that wrapping `dat` within a property will degrade performance and offer no benefit, since there's nothing that a property accessor could do (other than read/write the field) which wouldn't break some implementations.  Further, it may be necessary to use `Interlocked` methods with `dat` (or, if it's a struct, with fields thereof), but that wouldn't be possible if `dat` were wrapped in a property.

Note that while mutable data holders may be useful for types (mutable or not) which need to *hold* data, they cannot safely be used for data interchange in the same way that immutable types would.  For example, a statement like:

```
myData = myCollection.GetData(myKey);
```

would have a clear meaning if `GetData` returned an immutable class type or a struct ("mutable" or not) which did not contain references to mutable data.  If it returned a mutable class object, however, it would be unclear whether any changes to that object would consistently be ignored by the underlying collection, consistently result in clean updates to it, or cause some irksome or unpredictable behavior meeting neither description.

If one wished to have a collection return data in a mutable object, the correct paradigm would often be something like:

```
var myData = new WhateverType();
myCollection.GetData(myKey, myData);
myData.ModifySomehow();
myCollection.StoreData(myKey, myData);
```

Using that approach, there is a clear implication that `GetData` will cause `myData` to be populated with data from the collection, but `myCollection` would not be expected to keep a reference to it once the function was complete, nor would it use it for any other purpose.  `StoreData` would likewise copy information `myData` to its own internal data structure without keeping a reference.  Note that one advantage of this approach is that if the client code will be reading many data items within a loop, it may safely create one instance of `myData` outside the loop, and then reuse that same instance every time through.  Likewise, `myCollection` may be able to reuse the object instance associated with the key (copying data from the passed-in instance) without having to create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, I call them Entities. On my boring business applications, they *usually* map 1:1 to my DER.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a `Schema`.

This covers multiple uses such as representing a database table, or a deserialised record, or a DTO, etc