# How to get the behavior class from its data class when they are separated for the purpose of server-client communication?

Tags: java, design-patterns, client-server

I am writing a server-client program with the following idea (analogy for my real program). There are many types of shapes. The client represents the shapes to the user which can queue operations (like translation, rotation...) on them. The client sends the server the `id` and operation type. The server performs the operation and sends the new shape data back to the client.

In my current design I have the classes I detail below.

The `Shape` class sits only on the server, its subclasses contain algorithms for performing the operations for each shape (pretend that rotating a triangle and a square is very different). I do not want nor need that they be accessible to the client.

```
abstract class Shape {

    ShapeData data; // see below
    int[] plane; // some non-static parameter used by the server

    abstract void rotate();
    abstract void translate();
    abstract void rescale();
    // ... 10 more
}
```

The subclasses also sit only on the server

```
class Square extends Shape {

    void rotate()    { /* using ShapeData data and int[] plane ...*/ }
    void translate() { /*    "   */ };
    void rescale()   { /*    "   */ };
}

class Circle extends Shape {

    // same structure as square
}

// many more shapes
```

`ShapeData` is a class which holds the data of a shape (same data structure for all shapes). It is the class that is transfered from the server to the client from which the client can, for example, draw the shape. The class is also used by the server to perform the computations as seen above.

```
abstract class ShapeData implements Serializeable {

    int id; // after manipulating the shape represented by this class, the
            // client send this id back to the server

    int edgesNum;
    int width;
    int height;
    // ...

    // setters and getters
}
```

I understand that separating data and behavior is not an OO approach, but I treat this class as a DTO ([reference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160675/what-do-you-call-classes-without-methods)).

Getting the shape data from the shape is simple as it is "composed" into it, the problem is the other way around. The server keeps a `List<ShapeData>` which I retrieve from by `id`, but there is no obvious way to get the `Shape` on which to apply the transformation. This lead me to think that the design is bad.

Right now I keep a `Map<ShapeData, Shape>` to retrieve `Shape`. Another way is to add an `id` field to `Shape` with the same value as in its `ShapeData` and keep a `List<Shape>` from which I retrieve by `id` too.

Is the design bad or is there just some modification I can do to make it work "properly"?

Comment: Whoever downvoted my *first question on this site* might want to explain why instead of expecting users to mind-read what's wrong with it.

Comment: Why don't you want your clients to access the server-side class?

Comment: Why Map<ShapeData, Shape> instead of Map<Integer, Shape> so that you just need the id of the shape? Also, are your shapes persistent (i.e. stored in a database)?

Comment: @michaelsnowden "*Why don't you want your clients to access the server-side class?*" Because they don't need it. They can't do the transformations by themselves. "*Why Map<ShapeData, Shape> instead of Map<Integer, Shape>?*" So I can `get(data)` instead of `get(data.getID())`, I don't see any advantage for `Integer`. "*are your shapes persistent?*" `Shape` objects have to be stored (in memory in this case) in order to be retrieved, which is what the question is about.

Comment: So your clients have some way of rotating shapes other than using the Shape class?

Comment: @michaelsnowden No, as I explained, the clients only ask the server to perform the rotation for them and receive the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design is not inherently bad. Let's asume the transformations to be performed on the shapes are resource consuming and that is reason enough to have the behavior un the server.

**In MHO the matching id is the way to go.** You then pass a `List<ShapeData>` object back and forth. The client receives such a list and renders the graphics. The server receives such a list and matches every `ShapeData` with its corresponding `Shape` to make transformations.

**EDIT**

*(1) Why do you prefer this approach?*

To me every different type of `Shape` is a [flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) object, data is injected everytime a transformation is needed.

The id would help implement [Chain-of_responsability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern in which every processor object see whether the data is for them to work on they must pass it on to the next processor.

*(2) The client send only the id and transformation request (not included in my classes above), I don't see why it should pass the whole unchanged data class.*

So the servers doesn't have to have a permanent copy of every user's object. Objects live in the client, they are send to the server and the server sends them back transformed, servder doesn't need to have a synchronized copy of them. IMHO.

*(3) So you suggest that I go with keeping a `List<Shape>` and search it by id*

That way you could implement chain-of_responsability and flyweight patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Questions: (1) Why do you prefer this approach? For me, it seemed odd that an object (`Shape`) will contain the same field (`id`) that is already contained in an object (`ShapeData`) it itself contains. (2) The client send only the `id` and transformation request (not included in my classes above), I don't see why it should pass the whole unchanged data class. (3) So you suggest that I go with keeping a `List<Shape>` and search it by `id`?

Comment: @user1803551 So the client doesn't render the graphics? If the client renders the graphics then it should have access to `ShapeData` objects, shouldn't it?

Comment: It does render them and does have access to them. I was referring to "*The server receives such a list*" - the server doesn't receive `ShapeData`, just the `id` from it so it would know which one to retrieve from the `List<ShapeData>` is keeps, and an instruction for transformations.

Comment: @user1803551 I elaborated.

Comment: Thanks, I read more into the patterns. In the link is is said that `ShapeData` would have to be made immutable, is this even though they have a unique id?